# How can i calculate routes but not draw them on the map? Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

i have been trying to get this working for quite some time now, but cyclic references from the routes objects, asynchronous execution and whatnot made it hard for me to see the bigger picture.

I am also new to this, as one might have guessed.

So i try to get the closest three parkhouses from a START. So i calculate the routes to extract the e.routes.summary.totalDistance from them. However, i do not want them to be shown in the map just yet, because i want the three closest parkhouses and not every single one.
On the other hand, Leaflet Routing Machine does not calculate these routes if i do not `route.addTo(map)`.

It is a really hard time with this because it does defy all basics i have learned until now.
Can someone give me a hint how to do it?

```
            route = L.Routing.control({
                name: id,
                serviceUrl: 'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1',
                waypoints: coords,
                plan: L.Routing.plan(coords, {
                    createMarker: function() {
                        return null;
                    }
                }),
                addWaypoints: false,
                draggableWaypoints: false,
                show: false,
                showAlternatives: true
            }).on('routesfound', function(e) {
                for (let index = 0; index < e.routes.length; index++) {
                    tmpRoutes.push(e);
                    tmpDistances.push(e.routes[index].summary.totalDistance);
                    tmpWayPoints.push(e.routes[index].waypoints)
                }
                map.removeControl(e.routes);
            }).addTo(map);
            //map.removeControl(route);
        }
```

Comment: do you want to calculate distance of between two location???

Comment: yes but i dont not want the calculation routes to show up

Comment: You have to take lat and lng two points and move them to the server, then get the distance by calculating the distance from each api such as (google or osm or ...)

Comment: yeah thats what i do in the reference example, i dont want it to be drawn to the map tho. I guess i will try to use osmr's capabilities